# Create USER with bcrypt and authenticate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bcrypt

This is my **user.js** file, where i handle two requestes.

First the **POST /signup**, where the user enters an email, and a password so that i can store it in mongodb.

```
var express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

var User = require("../models/user");

router.post("/signup", (req, res, next) => {
  User.find({ email: req.body.email })
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
      if (user.length >= 1) {
        return res.status(409).json({
          message: "Mail exists"
        });
      } else {
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
          if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
              error: err
            });
          } else {
            const user = new User({
              _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
              email: req.body.email,
              password: hash
            });
            user
              .save()
              .then(result => {
                console.log(result);
                res.status(201).json({
                  message: "User created"
                });
              })
              .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).json({
                  error: err
                });
              });
          }
        });
      }
    });
});
```

Second the **POST /login**, where the user enters an email, and the password and with bcrypt i compare if the password matches the one in the db.

```
router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  User.find({ email: req.body.email })
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
      if (user.length < 1) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          message: "Auth failed"
        });
      }
      bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user[0].password, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(401).json({
            message: "Auth failed"
          });
        }
        if (result) {
          const token = jwt.sign(
            {
              email: user[0].email,
              userId: user[0]._id
            },
            process.env.JWT_KEY,
            {
                expiresIn: "1h"
            }
          );
          return res.status(200).json({
            message: "Auth successful",
            token: token
          });
        }
        res.status(401).json({
          message: "Auth failed"
        });
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});
```

**The problem is the following:** Whenever i try to create a user **/signup** using postman the request stays in "loading" and the server shuts down.

**POSTMAN body:** {
'emial': 'teste@gmail.com',
'password': '12345'
}

**Error in the server:** 
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [node-rest-shop-shard-00-01-pbcph.azure.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 4 to node-rest-shop-shard-00-01-pbcph.azure.mongodb.net:27017 timed out]

(node:1496) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

(node:1496) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0):

The `User.find` promise is being rejected because Node fails to connect to your MongoDB instance. This rejected promise tries to execute the first error handler that it comes across. In your case, it fails to find any catch() to handle this error. You can avoid this by adding a catch() to the promise chain at the end.
You should also look into why your Node instance cannot make a successful connection to your MongoDB instance.

```
router.post("/signup", (req, res, next) => {
  User.find({ email: req.body.email })
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
      if (user.length >= 1) {
        return res.status(409).json({
          message: "Mail exists"
        });
      } else {
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
          if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
              error: err
            });
          } else {
            const user = new User({
              _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
              email: req.body.email,
              password: hash
            });
            user
              .save()
              .then(result => {
                console.log(result);
                res.status(201).json({
                  message: "User created"
                });
              })
              .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).json({
                  error: err
                });
              });
          }
        });
      }
    }).catch(err => {    //Handle the error here.
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error: err
        });
    });
});
```

You should do the same for your login call.

Comment: Sry for the late response, now when i try to /login i receive the following error: **Error: secretOrPrivateKey must have a value**